# Is this date stale? python

Tags: python, date

I'm writing a function to flag and label stale dates (older than 6 months) in a report.

i.e.

```
def isStale(lineItemDate):
    if delta > 180:
        return " Stale"
    else:
        return ""
# where delta subtracts my lineItemDate from today in days
```

Trouble is, my raw data (lineItemDate) comes as a string: "Sep 5, 2020", so I'll need to convert that to something "datey" AND is comparable to whatever comes out of timedelta(days=180) which appears to be "2019-09-08 11:33:54.978144".

Each technique I try ends up with a bunch of lines of conversion for each date to compare. I'm trying to pare it down to a few lines.

Not sure why this won't pick up single digit days:

```
print(datetime.strptime("Sep 5, 2019", '%b %-d, %Y')))

ValueError("'%s' is a bad directive in format '%s'" % 
ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%b %-d, %Y'
```

Ultimately, is there an elegant way of comparing these two date elements so I can flag old ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `-`; although `strftime` uses `%d` to output a zero-padded day, `strptime` will parse a single-digit day with or without a leading zero.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("Sep 5, 2019", "%b %d, %Y")
datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 5, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime("Sep 05, 2019", "%b %d, %Y")
datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 5, 0, 0)
```

This is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail), but it's literally the last thing mentioned on the page. :)

> 9. When used with the strptime() method, the leading zero is optional for formats %d, %m, %H, %I, %M, %S, %J, %U, %W, and %V. Format %y does require a leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

My full solution, for posterity:

```
from datetime import datetime

def isStale(servdate):
    return (datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(servdate, '%b %d, %Y')).days > 180


print(isStale("Sep 15, 2019"))
print(isStale("Sep 5, 2019"))
```

.

```
False
True
```